# How to test input elements and events in Angular 6 unit tests

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have the following function to unit test. In the third line the test fails because i am seemingly mocking the event, that gets passed to the function, wrongly.

```
  unitTypeChanged(event: Event) {
    const target: HTMLSelectElement = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    if (this._unitsMap.has(target.value)) {
      this.units$ = of(this._unitsMap.get(target.value));
    } else {
      this.setUnits(target.value);
    }
  }
```

In the test I am dispatching an event to a generic select, but I am still getting a value of null and can't pass the test.

```
it('unitTypeChanged', () => {
  const selectElement: HTMLSelectElement = document.createElement('select');
  selectElement.value = 'Paul';
  const changeEvent: Event = new Event('change');
  selectElement.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);

  component.unitTypeChanged(changeEvent);
});
```

This is the test setup

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, HttpClientTestingModule, TranslateModule.forRoot(), SharedModule],
      declarations: [],
      providers: [{ provide: UnitService, useValue: { getUnitsByUnitTypeId: (arg1: string) => of([]) } }]
    }).compileComponents();

    // Language service static mock
    LanguageService.languages = [{ id: 'de', displayName: 'Deutsch', isNeutral: true }];

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditorRequirementFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // Standard initializations
    component.dataChanges = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<any>>(of(null));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

This is the error message by the unit test.

```
SUMMARY:
√ 0 tests completed
i 333 tests skipped
× 1 test failed

FAILED TESTS:
    × unitTypeChanged
      HeadlessChrome 84.0.4147 (Windows 10.0.0)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
        at EditorRequirementFormComponent.value [as unitTypeChanged] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/modules/content/editor/editor/editor-tabs/editor-requirement-form/editor-requirement-form.component.ts:84:39)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/modules/content/editor/editor/editor-tabs/editor-requirement-form/editor-requirement-form.component.spec.ts:81:15)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:358:1)
        at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:124:1)
        at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:561:1)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:576:1)
```

Comment: Could you give a [mre] - where is the rest of the component, the test setup, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

So the basic problem was that the event.target wasn't set when dispatching an event like this

```
selectElement.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

Instead of using the upper solution, we are now manipulating the event object with Object.defineProperty and overwrite the target, since the target property of the event interface is readonly.

```
Object.defineProperty(changeEvent, 'target', {writable: false, value: selectElement});
```